# How to create xcdatamodeld for particular database

Tags: ios, core-data

I've got a table with attributes:
Country, Place, Description etc.
A value of the country attribute can be repeated(one country can repeat two times or more).

I need to get from this DB:

1. All Countries. (for tableView)
2. All Places for a particular Country.(for tableView)
3. Other info for a particular Place. (for details
       view)

So, the question is what's the best way to implement the xcdatamodeld.
My thoughts:

1. I can create just an simple Entity without any relationships. But to
   get 1 and 2 points(described below) I have to go through all
   ManagedObjects and I thinks it's not thes best way.
2. To use setPropertiesToFetch:. I think it's a good way but I'm not sure is
   it okay to leave my database so simple without any relationships
   like(Country -> Place)
3. I thought to create three entities Country,
   Places, Details. And load necessary data from different entities.
   But it's my first experience with CoreData and I'm not sure does it
   make sense or no?

P.S. This is simple example. Real database can be much more bigger and complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example is trivial you could start with something as simple as:

[image]

This is how you would model it if you was ignoring the database - luckily CoreData will take care of the persistence for you and you can just use your models without thinking too much about tables

---

You have a concern about the efficiency once you click on a country. You should use an `NSFetchedResultsController` to handle efficiently batching data into the UI and working with a tableView. You would simply set up the `NSFetchedResultsController` to use a predicate something like:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"country == %@", self.selectedCountry];
```

---

Side note:

You should always profile to see if there is a real problem rather than working on opinion of estimation

Comment: Thank you! But in the Country entity I'm getting all Places in NSSet for each Country and it's not efficient I think(let me know if I'm wrong but if there's 200 countries and at least 100 places for each country it's a big quantity). Also I don't need all these Places at one moment. I need to get them by tapping on the particular Country. To loop resulted NSSet is not a best way I think. How can I get Places for a particular Country in this case? P.S. I can do this by looping NSSet but I want to know what's the most efficient way to do this.